# Add Class to Body via JavaScript using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a HTML template that I'd like to use for an ASP.NET project.

It's mobile navbar uses JavaScript ([classie.js](https://gist.github.com/desandro/4624426)) to assign the class "show-menu" to "body" element. However, as we're using ASP.net, this doesn't seem to work. May I know how do I get it to work? I tried making it run on serverside, but the implications are that the CSS doesn't work.

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
function toggleMenu() {
    if (isOpen) {
        classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
    } else {
        classie.add(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
}

init();
```

Here is my Master Page Code:

```
<body data-offset="90" data-target=".navigation" data-spy="scroll">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

I need a way to do it without converting my buttons to ASP.NET. Basically, what happens is when I click on the buttons, it adds "show-menu" but removes the class almost immediately, leaving it not working.

Comment: What happened to the JS code now?

Comment: @AlexisToby Hi, may I know what you mean? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: You need to do the action in the front end itself right?

Comment: @AlexisToby Yes!

Comment: Have you tried window.onload()?

Comment: @AlexisToby It's for a mobile menu nav bar so I don't think onload() works for what I'm trying to achieve. The problem is that it appears for a slight second and then disappears, so I'm not too sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was refreshing (didn't appear to be doing so on my screen) and all I had to do was add the following code to the button:

```
OnClick="return false;"
```

So for anyone out there facing the same issue, don't be an idiot like me.